# Configure when an Azure Virtual Machine is updated

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I have provisioned a small VM within Azure to run some macros within an instance of Chrome. The Chrome instance starts doing it's thing around 02:00 GMT finishing at around 04:00 GMT.

The problem I'm having is that Microsoft like to do any updates to the host machine in the early hours (for obvious reasons) and this can disrupt the work on the VM. The Chrome macros aren't very good at recovering from interruptions.

Is it possibly within Azure to specify when updates are done? This machine is idle for most of the day. Alternatively would the solution be to provision the machine in the Asia Pacific region so any maintenance would then presumably be done in day light hours GMT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. At this time you can't affect when Microsoft will apply host OS patches or updates.

Depending on what your macros are doing if you could instead get them into a script form you could look at something like Azure Automation which would let you perform the operations on a schedule and not have to have a hosted VM running out there.

Comment: I say macros, it's basically a bespoke Chrome Extension running in a loop, it's really not going to be easy to adapt. Anyway I suspected this would be the answer and appreciate it's a bit of a niche problem. I'll look at provisioning the server elsewhere or moving it to an on-premise box. Thanks for your help.